# Javascript, Php, Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with this my script.

```
$("#login").click(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var email = $("#email").val();
    var pass = $("#password").val();

    $.ajax({

        url : "login.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {userLogin:1, userEmail:email, userPassword:pass},
        success : function(data){

            if(data == "1"){

                alert(data);
            }

        }

    })
```

I want it to alert a value that I am getting from an echo in another php file

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['userLogin'])){

        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['userEmail']);

        $password = md5($_POST['userPassword']);

        $sql_login = "SELECT * from database where email = '$email' AND password = '$password'";

        $query_login = mysqli_query($con, $sql_login);

        $count_login = mysqli_num_rows($query_login);

        if($count_login == 1){

            $row_login = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_login);

            $_SESSION['uid'] = $row_login['user_id'];

            $_SESSION['name'] = $row_login['first_name'];

            echo "1";

        }


    }

    ?>
```

If I didn't put the alert(data) in an if condition, it displays the value I echo, but I need the condition to enable the right user logged in.

Comment: What is the value of 'data'?

Comment: @Turnip I'll bet a million dollars it's not "1"

Comment: That's why I asked ;p

Comment: If the data is "1", your if statement will be hit.  If it's not "1", your statement will not be hit.  Simple stuff.  Do some basic debugging.

Comment: without putting the alert in an if condition, the data brings 1, but upon putting the alert(data) in an if condition, the button doesnt do anything

Comment: or its better to use `dataType: "html",` in ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What can IF can also ELSE.

In your ajax add the **else** conditions to see if it helps uncover the issue:

```
if (data == "1") {
  alert('youre in');
} else {
  alert('try again');
}
```

And in your php, also account for the else condition (and do strict checking on that count of rows with ===):

```
if ($count_login === 1) {
  // code ...
  echo '1';
} else {
  echo 'Sorry, the login is incorrect';
}
```

Comment: thanks it really helps. now instead of displaying the data, I want it to open another page, i used window.location.href="new.php"; but its nt opening rather still displaying the echoed data

Comment: please select that as the answer - you may ask a new question if you like - i cannot answer from the limited info you have just provided in that comment.

Comment: hello, would you mind selecting this as the solution if it helped you?

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me, if i always echo "1", the alert(data) show 1, in an if condition and out, pls, echo something else if `isset($_POST['userLogin'])` or `$count_login == 1` are false, or put an

```
error : function(data) {
    $('body').append("<div>"+data.responseText+"</div>")
}
```

in your ajax, to debug the prob. Because in your .php file, when you echo nothing, it returns a data in error, not in success, maybe that's your prob.